# OpenCV freezing while splitting Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, g++, mat

I'm trying to split a camera frame into four pieces for processing with multiple threads. I create an array of 4 Mat an define each part an rectangle of my frame.

```
    Mat part[4];
    part[0] = threshold(Rect(0                  ,0                  , threshold.cols/2  , threshold.rows/2));
    part[1] = threshold(Rect(threshold.cols/2   ,0                  , threshold.cols/2  , threshold.rows/2));
    part[2] = threshold(Rect(0                  ,threshold.rows/2   , threshold.cols/2  , threshold.rows/2));
    part[3] = threshold(Rect(threshold.cols/2   ,threshold.rows/2   , threshold.cols/2  , threshold.rows/2));
```

This works fine, as far as I'm doing this in my main function. But for multithreading with pthread I'm not able to give arguments (like the part[]) to my function. So I'm trying to generate my Mat before, like:

```
[...]

Mat part[4];

[...]

 void *morphOps(void *threadid){
    long tid;
    tid = (long) threadid;

    Mat thresh = part[tid];
    Mat shrink = getStructuringElement( MORPH_ELLIPSE ,Size(erode_val,erode_val));
    Mat enlarge = getStructuringElement( MORPH_ELLIPSE,Size(dilate_val,dilate_val));

    erode(thresh,thresh,shrink);
    dilate(thresh,thresh,enlarge);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

[...]

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    [...]
    while(1){
         [...]

        cout << "splitting frame" << endl;
        part[0] = threshold(Rect(0                  ,0                  , threshold.cols/2  , threshold.rows/2));
        part[1] = threshold(Rect(threshold.cols/2   ,0                  , threshold.cols/2  , threshold.rows/2));
        part[2] = threshold(Rect(0                  ,threshold.rows/2   , threshold.cols/2  , threshold.rows/2));
        part[3] = threshold(Rect(threshold.cols/2   ,threshold.rows/2   , threshold.cols/2  , threshold.rows/2));

        [...]

    }

    [...]
}
```

Now this code freezes at line

```
cout << "splitting frame" << endl;
```

I have no clue why. Do i initialize the Mat-Array in a wrong way?

Comment: did you try to remove all the [...] code (except image capturing and thresholding)? does it still freeze? Can you post the code where you compute the Mat `threshold`? If possible, post complete code for a minimized example that still freezes.

Comment: Thank to your advice, i removed all the code and it worked. So i inserted the code step by step. The problem has been in my multicore handling. I created 4 threads, but called 5 exits. So this problem is solved, thank you for forcing me to reduce my code :)